# wrong setting an arraylist

Tags: java

I want to ask a question about arraylist. In my program I defined an arraylist and an user defined object. The problem is when I want to add an object to this arraylist, it adds object, but next time when I give the different values to user object, it sets values of the old object that I added before to the new one. I mean, for example I have 13 in my old object and the new one is 14, it makes the old one 14. I couldn't find a solution for this. I'M working on a drawing program. I'm posting some parts of the code.

```
     public class Tester extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

ArrayList<Lines> array = new ArrayList<Lines>();
    Lines l1;
      ...
    public Tester(){
    l1 = new Lines();
    l1.point1 = new Point();
    l1.point2 = new Point();
    l1.denklem = new int[3];
```

And thi is how I add object into arraylist

```
         else if(lineci == true){
        if(mouseclicks == 0){
            l1.point1.x = e.getX();
            l1.point1.y = e.getY();
            statusBar.setText( String.format( "Clicked at [%d, %d]", 
                    e.getX(), e.getY() ) );
            mouseclicks++;
            starter = false;
        }
        else if(mouseclicks == 1){
            l1.point2.x = e.getX();
            l1.point2.y = e.getY();
            statusBar.setText( String.format( "Clicked at [%d, %d]", 
                    e.getX(), e.getY() ) );
            mouseclicks = 0;
            int a = l1.point2.y - l1.point1.y;
            int b = l1.point1.x - l1.point2.x;
            int c = (l1.point2.x * l1.point1.y) - (l1.point1.x * l1.point2.y);
            l1.denklem[0] = a;
            l1.denklem[1] = b;
            l1.denklem[2] = c;

            array.add(l1);
        //  array3.add(l1);
            repaint();
        }

    }
```

When I click mouse, if lineci is true, it draws a line according to points. I get always last lines when I print elements of arraylist. If I draw 10 lines, 10 elements of the arraylist are the same. It never keeps old values inside arraylist. By the way boolean starter is not important. I just forget to remove it.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to comment?  Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply adding the **same object repeatedly** to the list.  Each addition to the list is merely adding a **reference** to the same object: `l1`.  Hence, when you update the state of `l1`, the old "object" also appears to have changed.

To rectify this you need to create a new instance of `Lines` for each addition you wish to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Use `l1.clone()` before changing the value inside if you want to keep all values same but one and the class is clonable or create a new object which is better for your case.

Comment: I disagree - Why clone() the existing object only to then completely change the state?  Better to create an entirely new instance of Lines IMO.

Comment: yes, i added extra info. If you need to keep all values in an object but change one then cloning is better. For this case, as you say, new object is better.

Comment: i think this would throw an exception if Lines class isn't clonable

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the original `l1` object, so it will modify the original `l1` object--whether or not it's in the list.

If you want to create a new object, *create a new object*.

Answer (score 0):

i think your l1 reference is still pointing the previous object added to the arrayList , you should override the reference as soon as you add the object to the arraylist .

by either

```
 l1 = new Lines();
```

or

```
l1 = null;
```